# Kivy app shows on the left bottom of screen

Tags: python, kivy, window, size, fullscreen

My Kivy app shows on left bottom of screen of phone (You can see in shared screenshot).But I want to make it fullscreen.I make value of "fullscreen" equal to 1 in "buildozer.spec" file.But nothing changed.Here is my code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader

Window.size = (320,640)

opart = False
vpart = False
rpart = False

och = False
vch = False
rch = False

ofin = False
vfin = False
rfin = False

fin = True

snd_part = SoundLoader.load("part.wav")
music = SoundLoader.load("music.wav")
music.play()

class Orange(ButtonBehavior,Image):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(Orange,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.source = "obal.png"
        self.size = (85,113)
        self.pos = (32,300)
    def on_press(self):
        global opart
        opart = True
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.todown,0.1)
    def todown(self,*args):
        global och
        if not och:
            snd_part.play()
            self.source = "effect.png"
            och = True
        else:
            self.x = 28
            self.source = "esma.png"
        if self.y > 250:
            self.y -= 4
        else:
            self.y = 250
            global ofin,fin
            ofin = True
            if vfin and rfin and fin:
                fin = False
                win.kill_platform()

class Violet(ButtonBehavior,Image):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(Violet,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.source = "vbal.png"
        self.size = (85,113)
        self.pos = (117,364)
    def on_press(self):
        global vpart
        vpart = True
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.todown,0.1)
    def todown(self,*args):
        global vch
        if not vch:
            snd_part.play()
            self.source = "effect.png"
            vch = True
        else:
            self.x = 113
            self.source = "yaxsiki.png"
        if self.y > 250:
            self.y -= 4
        else:
            self.y = 250
            global vfin,fin
            vfin = True
            if ofin and rfin and fin:
                fin = False
                win.kill_platform()

class Red(ButtonBehavior,Image):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(Red,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.source = "rbal.png"
        self.size = (85,113)
        self.pos = (202,300)
    def on_press(self):
        global rpart
        rpart = True
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.todown,0.1)
    def todown(self,*args):
        global rch
        if not rch:
            snd_part.play()
            self.source = "effect.png"
            rch = True
        else:
            self.x = 198
            self.source = "varsan.png"
        if self.y > 250:
            self.y -= 4
        else:
            self.y = 250
            global rfin,fin
            rfin = True
            if ofin and vfin and fin:
                fin = False
                win.kill_platform()

class Platform(Widget):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(Platform,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.size = (320,640)
        self.bgimage = Image(source = "bg.jpg")
        self.bgimage.size = (320,640)

        self.obeta = False
        self.vbeta = False
        self.rbeta = False

        self.obal = Orange()

        self.vbal = Violet()
        self.rbal = Red()
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.moveOrange,0.1)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.moveViolet,0.1)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.moveRed,0.1)

        self.bgimage.add_widget(self.obal)
        self.bgimage.add_widget(self.vbal)
        self.bgimage.add_widget(self.rbal)

        self.add_widget(self.bgimage)
    def moveOrange(self,*args):
        if not opart:
            if not self.obeta:
                 self.obal.y += 2
            else:
                self.obal.y -= 2
            if self.obal.y <= 280:
                self.obeta = False
            if self.obal.y >= 320:
                self.obeta = True
    def moveViolet(self,*args):
        if not vpart:
            if not self.vbeta:
                self.vbal.y += 1
            else:
                self.vbal.y -= 1
            if self.vbal.y <= 344:
                self.vbeta = False
            if self.vbal.y >= 384:
                self.vbeta = True
    def moveRed(self,*args):
        if not rpart:
            if not self.rbeta:
                self.rbal.y += 3
            else:
                self.rbal.y -= 3
            if self.rbal.y <= 280:
                self.rbeta = False
            if self.rbal.y >= 320:
                self.rbeta = True

class Platform2(Widget):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(Platform2,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.size = (320,640)
        self.bgimage = Image(source = "bg.jpg")
        self.bgimage.size = (320,640)
        self.add_widget(self.bgimage)


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.layout = GridLayout()
        self.platform = Platform()
        self.layout.add_widget(self.platform)
        return self.layout
    def kill_platform(self):
        self.platform = Platform2()
        self.layout.add_widget(self.platform)

win = MainApp()

win.run()
```

Here you can see screenshot.That's how it shows on my phone:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpSLm.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `Window.size = (320,640)` line with:

```
from kivy.utils import platform

if platform not in ["android", "ios"]:
    Window.size = (320,640)
```

Side notes, you might wanna change the attributes that use the 320x640 pixel count or at least smaller than it to something like `size_hint=(1,1)`. This answer might be unclear for most, but this is the best I can do

Comment: Thank you very much